# Generic TCP connections over a proxy?

Tags: proxy, tunneling, socks

Is there any way to achieve this command:

```
APPX --listen=127.0.0.1:1111 --socks5=someproxy.com:2222 --connect=server.com:3333
```

Then, if I connect to `127.0.0.1:1111`, it will be as if I connected to `server.com:3333`, except that it is transparently going through `someproxy.com:2222`.  E.g. `telnet 127.0.0.1:1111` will connect to `server.com:3333` while transparently going through `someproxy.com:2222`.

Is there any way to achieve `APPX`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:1111,reuseaddr,fork SOCKS4A:someproxy.com:server.com:3333,socksport=2222
```